# IceCast stream authentication

Tags: azure, audio-streaming, icecast

I'm using Icecast 2.3.3.

I want to use URL stream authentication, the problem is that the authentication server url is not called by Icecast server and i don't know why. The Icecast server runs on Linux machine on Azure, the auth server is Azure Web App. I tried different configurations and i got unexpected errors.
First, for:

```
<mount type="normal">
    <mount-name>/local.ogg</mount-name>
    <authentication type="url">
        <option name="stream_auth" value="http://localhost/"/>
    </authentication>
</mount>
```

I got this error (which I understand):

```
[2015-05-13  18:36:52] EROR connection/_handle_connection HTTP request parsing failed
[2015-05-13  18:36:52] WARN auth_url/url_stream_auth auth to server http://localhost/ failed with Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
[2015-05-13  18:36:52] WARN auth/stream_auth_callback Failed auth for source "/local.ogg"
```

Then, for:

```
<mount type="normal">
    <mount-name>/ip.ogg</mount-name>
    <authentication type="url">
        <option name="stream_auth" value="http://123.45.67.89/"/>
    </authentication>
</mount>
```

Again, the error, as I expected is (this ip is random):

```
[2015-05-13  18:37:34] EROR connection/_handle_connection HTTP request parsing failed
[2015-05-13  18:37:35] WARN auth_url/url_stream_auth auth to server http://123.45.67.89/ failed with Connection timed out after 15008 milliseconds
[2015-05-13  18:37:35] WARN auth/stream_auth_callback Failed auth for source "/ip.ogg"
```

But then, when I want to use my Web App

```
<mount type="normal">
    <mount-name>/blast.ogg</mount-name>
    <authentication type="url">
        <option name="stream_auth" value="http://blast.azurewebsites.net/"/>
    </authentication>
</mount>
```

I don't get an error that would explain to me what's wrong

```
[2015-05-13  18:38:29] EROR connection/_handle_connection HTTP request parsing failed
[2015-05-13  18:38:30] WARN auth/stream_auth_callback Failed auth for source "/blast.ogg"
```

Is there anything I should know about Icecast stream_auth function? Or maybe I have to set up my VM with Icecast differently?

If anyone have a working example of use of stream_auth, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: 2.3.3 through 2.4.1 are vulnerable to remote DoS CVE-2015-3026 - Upgrade urgently to 2.4.2 before using in production!

Comment: Make sure your log level is '4' aka DBUG. Also look at logging on the target webserver to make sure if URL was requested etc.

Comment: On Icecast website the current version is 2.4.1. How can i get the newest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the icecast install process doesn't check for availability of libcurl. Which is needed for this functionality. Check your config.log for messages like "libcurl not found"
If that is the case, then you can run "apt-get install libcurl4-gnutils-dev " to install libcurl. That should fix this error.

Comment: Updating to 2.4.2 and installing the libcurl solved the problem, thanks @orn